# Sending SignalR timed messages

Tags: websocket, signalr

As I mentioned in the title.

Can we write methods such as send a message to all clients after 30 seconds, send a message after 60 seconds, by the Hub when certain invokes are running?

Answer (score 0):

If you will sleep your thread inside of hub method, you will block connection from handling other invocations, so you can simply try to make new hub connections for invocation of those blocking methods.

Or you can try to make some streaming calls with stub streaming parameters, which don't block message processing queue of signalr, like this

```
public async Task TriggerDelayedInvocation(IAsyncEnumerable<int> stream)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    await Clients.All.SendAsync(...);
}
```

On the front end you will also need to provide dummy stream parameter

```
var dummySubject = new signalR.Subject();
connection.invoke("TriggerDelayedInvocation", dummySubject);
dummySubject.complete();
```

(sending link for ASP.NET Core signalr tutoial for this)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Or you can try to use some background service helpers like hangfire. But you will need to use some hack to not access Clients property of disposed hub, because hub will be disposed after invocation finishes. For example like this:

```
var clients = Clients;
BackgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    clients.All.Invoke(...);
});
```

Or, probably the best way, you can make some ASP.NET core controller which will allow you to use Thread.Sleep synchronously, or queue some background jobs without hacks.
To access clients you will need to provide HubContext like in this tutorial
(sending for asp.net core signalr, but similar mechanism should be implemented by old signalr)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0